# How to ANALYZE regexes for possible vulnerabilities?

Tags: regex, algorithm, denial-of-service

[This article](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~hxt/research/reg-exp-sec.pdf) describes two ways to detect if a regex is vulnerable to catastrophic backtracking (and thus ReDOS, or regex denial of service, attacks):

- Fuzzing - essentially a brute-force to see if there are inputs that lag
- Analysis - looks at regexes intelligently, and is able to pinpoint *where* the slowdown occurs in the regex.

An analysis tool was built for as part of the research, but I'm not sure if it was actually released as an open-source tool (as it said it might be).

So my question is: based on the linked article, how would I analyze a regex for vulnerabilities? I'm not looking for Fuzzing, as it is more time consuming and fails to identify the location of the problem.

I'm aware that another question asked about ways, in general, (and the answers were all either Fuzzing or "it's too hard") to find "bad regexes".

Comment: Regex is often build to match - so for searching bad regexes, it's usually a good start to take a look at the cases where it doesn't. Also a high number of unlimited quantifiers, especially if nested, not possesive and used for `.`-Matches is worth a closer look.

Comment: The former won't work because the triggering inputs can be very rare. The latter, well, by the time you finish, you might as well just swap out the regexp engine you're using for RE2 or something.

Comment: When it matters, you should use a regex implementation that doesn't backtrack

Comment: @MattTimmermans I don't believe that every language has one

Comment: [RE2's readme](https://github.com/google/re2) lists bindings for C, Erlang, Inferno, Node.js, OCaml, Perl, Python, and Ruby. Apparently, there are Lua and PHP bindings as well. That's not *every language* but it's a pretty good sample.

Comment: @rici I was thinking about Java

Comment: @Laurel I've got one for java (http://mtimmerm.github.io/dfalex/), and RE2 has wrappers for most other languages (https://github.com/google/re2)

Comment: @MattTimmermans I guess if I was doing something _truly_ critical I'd go through the hassle of bringing external libraries. It would be nice if languages just used better regex engines in the first place though.

Answer (score 1):

Not really base on your article but one measurement of the complexity is the [star height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_height) of your regular expression.

[This tool](https://github.com/substack/safe-regex) allows you to detect dangerous regexp with star height over one.

Note that this should only be used as an indication. I've used regexps with star height > 1 that can parse few KB of text per ms.